# How to give a player an effect while near a certain mob?

Tags: minecraft-commands

I’m trying to make it so that players within 5 blocks of a wolf get a defense boost, how do I pull that off?

Comment: How much research have you done?  I only ask because we value users that show they've done some work trying to solve their own problem prior to asking a question here.

Comment: Please read the [tour] and ideally also some of the [help] before asking. And the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com) is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It is in fact very simple, and took just a bit of messing around. There are a few steps to building the command:

1. Build need a  <kbd>Repeat</kbd>   <kbd>Always active</kbd>  command block
2. You'll need a `/execute at` command, so the command is executed from a different position than that of the command block.
3. Specify the entity selector: `@e[type=Wolf]`, so that the command is executed at every wolf.
4. Create the command you want to apply on players around wolves: `run effect @a[distance=..5] minecraft:resistance 1 0`

Now combine all that into one command:

```
/execute at @e[type=minecraft:wolf] run effect give @a[distance=..5] minecraft:resistance 1 0
```

This command gives the `Resistance` effect to every plpayer that is 5 or less blocks away from a wolf.